# LLDB Scripting Bridge Expression

Tags: objective-c, lldb

I am trying to get LLDB’s SBValue.EvaluateExpression (not Frame's) working. It consistently fails and shows an area of 0.

The Objective-C Triangle class's area method does indeed compute and return a non-zero value, but the summary text is always "Triangle with area 0"

Does the expression need to be in some different format? Does it only work with properties?

````
def ObjCTriangleSummary( valueObj, infoDict ):
    exprOptions = lldb.SBExpressionOptions()
    exprOptions.SetLanguage( lldb.eLanguageTypeObjC )
    areaObj = valueObj.EvaluateExpression( "area" , exprOptions )

    area = areaObj.GetValueAsUnsigned()

    return "Triangle with area {}".format( area )```
````

Comment: Also, I have had EvaluateExpression succeeding for a C++ object's "length()".

Comment: The way errors from EvaluateExpression propagate is in the `SBError` object carried by the resultant SBValue.  You can check for errors with `areaObj.error.success` and if that is False, you can see the actual error with: "areaObj.error.description".  Did this EvaluateExpression succeed, and if it failed, what was the error?

Comment: Thanks! I'll pursue that.